# RF ferrite core inductor airgap magnetic field calculation

Tags: rf, transformer, inductor, magnetic-flux, balun

I was interested which formula I could apply to calculate the maximum field strength in an airgap located within an ferrite core, in my particular case I am looking at a "binocular" type wideband transformer/inductor core.
My intent is to use the core as an inductor with a single coil driven with Rf frequency and to obtain a flux within the airgap.
For reference please see the attached picture.

Would it be true that for a fixed turns count and amperage in order to increase the field strength within the airgap , I could make the part of the core that has the airgap thinner as this would concentrate the flux in less area? (assuming the flux with respect to area isn't too much to saturate the core at that part)

PS. I suppose the field strength in the airgap would vary also based on the driving RF frequency since the impedance of the inductor would change and so would the amperage for a fixed voltage?
My intention is to have as wide of a frequency range as possible starting from few Mhz up to as far as the ferrite can go , possibly 1-2 Ghz, although I read of some ferrites being able to function up to 20Ghz.

[image]

Comment: Leave a link to the data sheet of the ferrite with the gap please.

Comment: That core is not considered to have an airgap. The two holes are winding space.

Comment: @Andy aka I don't have a specific ferrite in mind at the moment , I was thinkig more in general terms to consider the approximate field strength achievable.    yes I know these cores normally don't have airgaps but the picture is just an example , for my purposes I would need to have an airgap

Comment: :@Andy aka I was thinking of a general formula where I can put in my parameters and see the outcome, Oh one questions if I say calculate the field strength in the airgap for a specific ferrite core , then if I simply extend the length of that core then the maximum field strength in the gap would remain the same , because the coil length within the ferrite also increases proportionally, correct? I am speaking about the case where all other sizes stay the same jsut the length is increased, like for the core I shown in the picture?, thanks